# Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h', but it should?

Tags: c++, header, stdafx.h

```
#include <stdafx.h>
```

i checked [error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory in VS 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545641/error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-stdafx-h-no-such-file-or-directory-in) 
but it still didn't help. im using precompiled headers. Usually i start out with a template ive saved for myself. that has all the headers i like, and in the past the include has worked. Also i would attach code, but its not allowing me to access it on any proj at all. even a simple hello world.

Comment: usually it does work, like literally, less than 3 days ago it did, now it works on nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `#include "stdafx.h"`.

This will change the way the compiler looks for the header - namely, it will check the local directory.

[Here is the SO question for further reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename).

Comment: @TerraPhase: `""` vs. `<>`. Try it.

Comment: i feel like such an idiot now of course XD thanks :P